# Conditionally Aggregate Rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table of user visits like such:

```
SELECT * FROM visits ORDER BY start_time;

 user_id |     start_time      |      end_time
---------+---------------------+---------------------
      10 | 2016-06-01 05:45:00 | 2016-06-01 06:00:00
      10 | 2016-06-01 06:05:00 | 2016-06-01 06:30:00
      10 | 2016-06-01 06:10:00 | 2016-06-01 06:40:00
      10 | 2016-06-02 10:00:00 | 2016-06-01 10:30:00
      10 | 2016-06-03 13:00:00 | 2016-06-01 14:00:00
```

I want to "merge" rows where the visits overlap, or are within 10 minutes of each other, like so:

```
 user_id |     start_time      |      end_time
---------+---------------------+---------------------
      10 | 2016-06-01 05:45:00 | 2016-06-01 06:40:00
      10 | 2016-06-02 10:00:00 | 2016-06-01 10:30:00
      10 | 2016-06-03 13:00:00 | 2016-06-01 14:00:00
```

- The first 3 rows, are merged into 1 since the first two rows are within 5 minutes (less than 10 minutes) of each other and the third row overlaps the second
- The last three rows are unchanged since no rows are within 10 minutes of them

I don't think this is possible using `GROUP BY` since the grouping function return value for each row would depend on multiple rows. I was thinking **window functions** could help, but have been struggling to build the query.

I am using AWS Redshift

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window/analytic functions for this.  I think this version works on your data:

```
select user_id, min(start_time) as start_time, max(end_time) as end_time
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when start_time > prev_end_time + interval '10' minute
                      then 1 else 0
                 end) over (partition by user_id order by start_time) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(end_time) over (partition by user_id order by start_time) as prev_end_time
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by grp, user_id;
```

This methodology does not work for all data.  In particular, it assumes that there are no duplicate start times for a user.  It can also get funky with complex multiple overlaps.  But, for many situations, this logic does work.